# import divided css file in react components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hello I have my components split and using react-router-dom and i decided to split css for each component for example `Main.jsx - Main.css` `CustomerBase.jsx - customerbase.css` but problem is that css are joined and if i set body color to white for `CustomerBase.jsx` and yellow for `Main.jsx` it will use white for both `Main and CustomerBase` How can i prevent this?

like so:
customerbase.css

```
body{
    background: white;
}
```

main.css

```
body{
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgb(236, 107, 32); 
}
```

Comment: I think, the react styled component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) is that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't be using body tag multiple times.

You can have a wrapper id name (#my_component_id) for each component, And inside its CSS file, add the #my_component_id before your styling to just affect only this component. or if you are using something like Sass, you can just wrap all your styling inside the #my_component_id

```css
#title-component {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#title-component h1 {
    color: green;

}

#content-component {
    background: white;
}

#content-component h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="title-component">
  <h1>Hi There, Here you have green h1 tag.</h1>
</div>

<div id="content-component">
  <h1>But Here, You can see a red h1 tag!</h1>
</div>
```